# How can i get data from today's date and before?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm calling data from a table from database. I'm adding WHERE statement to filter data that are registered from today until 14days ago. Below are example of my code:

```
$data=DB::connection('oracle_mybase')->table('my_dndomain')
          ->where('my_dndomain.domain_status','=',86)
          ->where('my_dndomain.domain_reg_date','>=',DB::raw('to_date(sysdate)-14'))
          ->where('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.com.my')
          ->orwhere('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.org.my')
          ->orwhere('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.net.my')
          ->orwhere('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.my')
          ->get();
```

But i couldn't get the data.

Comment: You should adopt Eloquent Models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereBetween`

```
whereBetween('date', array(Carbon::now()->subWeeks(2), Carbon::now()))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `->whereBetween('my_dndomain.domain_reg_date',array($now->subDays(14), $now))`

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$twoweeksago = Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDay(14);

$data=DB::connection('oracle_mybase')->table('my_dndomain')
          ->where('my_dndomain.domain_status','=',86)
          ->whereBetween('my_dndomain.domain_reg_date',array($twoweeksago, $now))
          ->where('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.com.my')
          ->orwhere('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.org.my')
          ->orwhere('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.net.my')
          ->orwhere('my_dndomain.domain_extension','=','.my')
          ->whereDate('field_name', '<', $now)
          ->get();
```

Comment: This will not work, because `$now->subDays(14)` will change `$now` object. You need to call `now()` again to get today's date.